# Merge tags 'logging' and 'logs'

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I think the following tags should be merged.

- [logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/logs): 88 questions
- [log](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/log): 54 questions
- [logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/logging): 258 questions

These seem synonymous to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bad idea.

https://serverfault.com/tags/logging/synonyms